# How to access List Item contents in SharePoint via PHP SOAP?

Tags: php, sharepoint, soap

I'm able retrieve the list items on Sharepoint via the code below:

```
  public function getListItems($listName){
    $params     = ['listName' => $listName];
    try {
      $rawXMLresponse = $this->soapClient->GetListItems($params)->GetListItemsResult->any;
      return $rawXMLresponse;
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
      $this->writeError($fault);
    }
  }
```

In Sharepoint the retrieved list items that I have are links that contain Documents (Folder, Files, etc.) What I need to do is to somehow display that contents for each link.

These are the available operations that I can use:

[image]

I already tried using the **GetAttachmentCollection** which receives a listName and a listItemID which just returns an empty array for any given ListItemID that I put:

```
public function getAttachmentCollection($listName){
    $params     = [
        'listName' => $listName,
        'listItemID' => '15'
    ];

    try {
        $rawXMLresponse = $this->soapClient->GetAttachmentCollection($params)->GetAttachmentCollectionResult->any;
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($rawXMLresponse);
        $result = array();
        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Attachments') as $attachments) {
            foreach($attachments->getElementsByTagName('Attachment') as $attachment) {
                $result[] = $attachment->nodeValue;
            }
        }

        var_dump($result);


    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        $this->writeError($fault);
    }
}
```

I have also tried asking this question to the Sharepoint Stack but they recommend switching REST API which is not an option for me.

Here's the list items response XML:

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:dt="uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
       xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<rs:data ItemCount="15">
    <z:row ows_LinkTitle="DOCUMENTS" ows_Is_x0020_Web="1" ows_Hidden="0" ows_Offline_x0020_Support="1"
           ows_Offline="1" ows_Offline_x0020_Only_x0020_Wifi="1" ows_Offline_x0020_Download_x0020_Doc="1"
           ows_Offline_x0020_Max_x0020_Document="10.0000000000000" ows_Swipe_x0020_Documents="1"
           ows_Offline_x0020_Background="1" ows_Layout_x0020_Mode="Normal" ows_TabsEnable="0"
           ows_ManualOrderSupport="1" ows_Preview_x0020_On_x0020_Tap="1" ows_ShowInSaveToOtherLocation="1"
           ows__Level="1" ows_UniqueId="15;#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" ows_FSObjType="15;#0"
           ows_Created_x0020_Date="15;#2018-06-13 11:06:50" ows_Modified="2018-06-13 11:09:01" ows_MetaInfo="15;#"
           ows_Title="DOCUMENTS" ows_ID="15" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_Created="2018-06-13 11:06:50"
           ows_FileLeafRef="15;#15_.000" ows_PermMask="0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ows_FileRef="15;#Lists/ListName/15_.000"
           ows__ModerationStatus="0"/>

    14 more ...

</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample XML output ? Thank you

Comment: Hello, I've provided a sample XML on my recent edit. Thanks!